# Redeployment a web part in sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint, deployment, sharepoint-2010, web-parts

I have a sharepoint project and i have a web part in my project.

web part contains a custom http handler lets call it as

```
custonHttpHandler.ashx
```

in my code i m calling this file by javascript,

in my ashx file i have a such code

```
context.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
new CustomHandlerCore().ExecuteMethod(context);
```

CustomHandlerCore class is in my sharepoint web part project folders.

now i m packaging the project and deploying it by powershell but still the old code is working.

what should i do?

Comment: How are you including an http handler in a web part? As far as I know it needs to be inside _layouts